# Frogs or mice or both - how to get rid of?

Tags: shed

So, I know my remote pump house has had rats in the past - I know what their poop looks like and I've plugged all holes that might allow a rat to get in. I've not seen rat poop for months.

I do see other new poop (because I vacuumed and new stuff has shown up). See pic below. I'm not too familiar with frog poop. I'm pretty sure I know what mouse poop looks like.

I have also caught 2 (Tree?) small frogs in the past. I generally catch them sitting on the moist brass/metal fittings of the piping. I released them 30 yards away in an ornamental pond I have.

I figure if a small frog can get in then a mouse can get in. I've not seen a mouse.

What do you think I have? How to keep them out? Should I just set some mouse snap traps (sorry for how cruel this may sound but I just can't have mice...or frogs...)?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably not a frog. I have not noticed frog dropping but toad droppings are surprisingly large for the size of the animal.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I too noticed the size of the toad poop in the literature. Just not sure about the size of frog poop from small (1" and 1.5") frogs - I caught them sitting on the piping and that filter stand you see in the pic. I've never seen (or heard) a mouse in the pump house (but I know that doesn't mean they are not there). There's fiberglass insulation in between the studs so they'd have plenty of hiding/nesting places.

Answer (score 2):

In my pump house I have had bad mouse problems too. Opened up a large LB fitting and came face to face with a large live mouse. They had also built a huge nest in the electrical gutter (6x6).  Now I have ultrasonic pest deterrents as well as old fashioned moth balls scattered in various electrical spaces. , mice and rats hate that smell and I haven't any any problems since. The cheap ultrasonic pest deterrents don't work all that well, if you choose to go that route, get some high end ones. And seal up entry points with steel wool, it's a great deterrent.

Comment: Te paradichlorobezene mothballs might work, particularly if the enclosure can be sealed more tightly, e.g. with plastic sheeting. My experience with ultrasonic pest control is that it did nothing, except perhaps annoy dogs.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson upvote for the steel wool suggestion ... soap filled scouring pads are a good choice because the soap will deter rodents that would normally chew on plain steel wool

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I tend to agree with you that many of the ultrasonic pest deterrents aren't all that great, but I've had some success with the higher end units that cost like $50-75, but the cheapies  you get a home depot for $10 for 3 aren't helpful.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I have used steel wool in other exclusion efforts but my problem with this new-to-me pump house is how many gaps there are around the entry double doors. Does anyone know if using mothballs will drive out current dwellers (or must a I trap them) or will the fumes act to just deter new ones from entering?

Comment: @coderjohn  They really don't like the mothball fumes (neither do I, but I'm not living in my pumphouse!)  I think you need a multi-pronged approach!  Moth balls, steel wool and this clever invention called the "rolling log mouse trap"  I haven't used it, but from what I hear, it's highly effective.   Here is a quick vid on you tube showing it, very simple.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SIlYiiCGLI